# error message following the openwhisk tutorial

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I'm following the tutorial at: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html

problems at step 3 of tutorial:

copied and pasted command:

`wsk action invoke --blocking --result hello --param name 'Bernie' --param place 'Washington, DC'`

get error:

```
←[31merror: ←[0mInvalid argument(s): DC'. An action name is required.
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
```

running the previous steps of tutorial were fine

Comment: Is this using Windows by any change?

Answer (score 1):

It's detecting the comma ',' in your place parameter. Try using "Washington, DC" in double quotes.

Comment: Right you are. This is even a known bug, already filed here: https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/1291